# CFLDAP:- populate FULL data from Active directory, rather than a single userid or username

Tags: coldfusion, active-directory

I have a form field “Names” that gets populated from an Active Directory.
I am using CFLDP to connect to the Active Directory.

```
<cfldap action="QUERY" 
    name="results" 
    attributes="cn,sn,dn,department,mail,userid,etc." 
    start="dc=##,dc=##,dc=##" 
    filter="##=##" 
    server="00.00.0004" 
    username="me" 
    password="mePASWD">
<cfdump var="#results#">
```

When I see the result it throws the data(CN, DEPARTMENT ,DN ,MAIL, SN, USERID , UUSERID
) only for the Username="me" AND Password="mePASWD". **WHERE AS I WAS HOPING IT WILL LIST THE DETAILS OF ALL THE USERS IN THE ACTIVE DIRECTORY.**

ULtimatelyt I want to list theses “names” as a list and enable The user to select any “Name/Names”.

Please help how to populate all the data from Active directory rather than only a single userid or username.
I am using CF8 and Windows Server 2003 AD/LDAP standard.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears that your user account only has access to your own record.

You will need to use a username and password for an account with wider access to the directory.

Alternatively, you may be able to use an anonymous bind depending on what your system administrator has enabled.

I find it useful to use a [standalone LDAP browser](http://jxplorer.org/) to troubleshoot ldap issues.

Comment: If you want to explore your active directory, then you can use [AD Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963907.aspx).

Comment: I use LDAP Administrator personally, but AD Explorer works the same. I found LDAP Admin easier to use http://www.ldapadministrator.com/